# Get Select ID onchange Jquery

Tags: jquery

In my application i am trying to get id of select box when accessing onchange function.
Here 2 select box are here, both point to same function **check**.How can i get id of select box when selecting these two select box.ie example1 and example 2.

```
<select id="example1" onchange='check()'>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>Example 2 :
<select id="example2" onchange='check()'>
    <option id="1">one</option>
    <option id="2">two</option>
    <option id="3">three</option>
    <option id="4">four</option>
</select>
```

My Jquery Function, But it only getting id of first select box.

```
<script>
function check(){
 var id = $('select').attr('id');
 alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use ***$(this)***

```
<script>
    function check(){
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

I would suggest you to get rid of inline JavaScript (remove *onchange* from select elements). And then use this code:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="example1">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>Example 2 :
<select id="example2">
    <option id="1">one</option>
    <option id="2">two</option>
    <option id="3">three</option>
    <option id="4">four</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:**
I assume that you use jQuery because you wrote *$('select')* in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the inline function call to pass `this`:

```
onchange='check(this)'
```

Then your function will look like this:

```
function check(t){
    var id = t.id;
    alert(id);
}
```